# How to rename files with filename from one txt file to filename from another txt file in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, command-line

I have some filename in a .txt file and some other filename in another .txt file. I want to rename files stored in that folder from filename in the text file line by line.

FROM :

```
$cat oldname.txt
file1.mp4
file2.mp4
```

TO :

```
$cat newname.txt
video1.mp4
video2.mp4
```

I want some bash script that can execute `mv` command line by line for each file.
Like

```
$mv file1.mp4 video1.mp4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a proper loop over the file to rename with `bash` . Open the files separately in different file-descriptors.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read oldname <&3 && read newname <&4
do
     mv "$oldname" "$newname"
done 3<oldname.txt 4<newname.txt
```

Comment: Thanks that worked for me..

Comment: @Inian: it did work for me.  Learnt a new thing from you, thanks!  I upvoted your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
while read oldname; do 
    read -u 3 newname
    echo mv $oldname $newname
done < oldname.txt 3< newname.txt
```

This will merely echo the commands.  If you like the result, omit the `echo`.