# Bash - How to rename files inside a directory based on names.txt

Tags: linux, bash, file-rename

I'm sorry I can't provide the actual filenames for privacy reasons.

`names.txt` contains several groups of lines separated by a single `empty line`. Each group pertains to a particular file. The number of lines in each group of lines varies. The only similarity between these groups of lines is that every 1st lines refers to the oldname of a certain file while every 2nd line refers to the desired newname for the said file.

These lines have no spaces in them. There are some other characters like numbers, underscore, ampersand and forward slash though.

`names.txt` is inside the same directory and it looked like this:

```
a1.pdf
Newname_for_a1.pdf
--some-texts--

b2.pdf
Newname_for_b2.pdf
--some-texts--
--some-texts--

c3.pdf
Newname_for_c3.pdf
--some-texts--
--some-texts--

d4.pdf
Newname_for_d4.pdf
--some-texts--
--some-texts--
--some-texts--

--more_texts_below--
```

The oldname starts with a lowercase while the newname starts with uppercase both with a `.pdf` extension

`ls` will give

```
a1.pdf
b2.pdf
c3.pdf
d4.pdf
names.txt
several-filenames-below
```

Can I do this in Bash? Please help.

**edit.**
Initially I want to work on having 2 .txt files, oldnames.txt and newnames.txt and then I realized maybe there is another way of doing this with just 1 txt file.

What I've tried already is watched some video tutorials about regular expressions in relation to grep but I feel like i will understand it better if I will do actual text manipulations such as finding, moving, renaming files since I am also in the process of sorting and organizing some hundred Gbs of media files and personal documents.

I'm looking into this thread now

> [How to rename files with filename from one txt file to filename from another txt file in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41339332/how-to-rename-files-with-filename-from-one-txt-file-to-filename-from-another-txt)

**edit2**
I can now grep the instances of 1st lines (oldnames) in each group from `names.txt` by
`grep --color -n -E "^[a-z].*\.pdf$" names.txt`
and the instances of 2nd lines (newnames) in each group from `names.txt` by
`grep --color -n -E "^[A-Z].*\.pdf$" names.txt`

Comment: Why do you think we care about the real names?

Comment: Of course you can do this in bash. What part of this are you having trouble with?

Comment: Please clarify how the file should be parsed. The lines that you need to skip over all begin with `--`? Or the two lines with the filenames are always after a blank line?

Comment: @Barmar all of it. The implementation. I just started exploring the cli so yeah very little knowledge.

Comment: @Barmar yeah after the blank is always the oldname followed by the newname. The lines with -- is just descrition of the file

Comment: Hint: Use a `while read line` loop. Inside the loop you can check if the current line is empty. If so, you do `read oldname` and `read newname` to read the next two lines, then rename the file.

Comment: You'll need to add a special case for the first two lines, since there's no blank before it.

Comment: from your question, I do not understand what do you want to do. What is the input and what is the desired output.

Comment: @DudiBoy yeah I think it is vague. I will try to re-write it but basically what i want to do is rename my files in this directory based on the infos I've written on names.txt. As you can see on my OP there is a pattern where the first line in each subgroup separated by a blank line is the oldname immediately followed by a new line containing the desired newname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since rename operation with `mv` command is not reversible.

1. Suggesting to write all `mv` commands into a file `renames.sh`.

   ```
   awk '{print "mv \""$1"\"", "\""$2"\""}' RS="\n\n" RSnames.txt > renames.sh
   ```
2. Inspect and correct the `renames.sh` file.

Note: clear all quotes `'` and/or double-quotes `"` from your file names. Each file name needs to be wrapped in double-quotes `"`. Script will fail if there is `'` or `"` in file name.

3. Execute all `mv` commands in a `renames.sh` file. By running the `renames.sh` files as a script.

   ```
   bash renames.sh
   ```

#### `awk` script explantion:

#### `RS="\n\n"`

Set `awk` record separator to `empty line`.

#### `print "mv \""$1"\"", "\""$2"\""`

Print a bash command `mv "file1" "file2"` .

File1 retrieved from 1st `awk` field `$1`, File2 retrieved from 2nd `awk` field `$2`.

Comment: thanks will try this asap. What do you mean with "Assuming every file record is 5 lines" on 1.

Comment: it seems to work a bit for few instances of oldname (1st line), newname (2nd line). The awk command you shared captured some combinations of 1st and 2nd lines both wrapped in double quotes.  I am trying to explain that in names.txt there are groups of lines separated by a blank line, only the 1st and 2nd lines in each group has .pdf extensions the 3rd lines and so on are just descriptions and remarks. The awk command also captured some of them.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is maybe we can only target the 1st lines(oldnames) and 2nd lines(newnames) in each groups.

Comment: Updated `awk` script to your request

Comment: whoa worked like a charm this time @Dudi.

Comment: Yeah worked like Skadoosh! Maybe you can recommend a reference material for effectively and efficiently learning awk. I am just starting to understand grep xargs and find aotm. "Student forever". Man I really like that line. Do you think I'm late to learn this things at 40 now?

Comment: I am 58 and learning new things every day. I review  questions and answers. And suggesting `awk` tutorial . https://www.tutorialspoint.com/awk/index.htm